# No merge option for un-shelved changes

Tags: tfs, merge

I'm using TFS 2010 version.

I have shelved some minor changes in may and now I want to include them in production version of my application. So, I do the un-shelve operation and then I issue Get latest... command and this is where the trouble starts:

Files have changed since and conflicts are found but I'm not offered the merge option which I need. I only have options to take server version or to keep local version. Why no merge option? Conflicts can even be auto merged but I'm happy to do it by hand if necessary.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: what happens if you do the get latest first, and then the merge from shelveset, remember that your shelveset is very stale and later Changesets would normally take precedence

Comment: Thanks. It's still the same. I think I will need to merge this carefully by copy&paste method.